# How to get DataReader with EF?

Tags: entity-framework-6, sql-server-2014, sqldatareader

I have a process that currently uses Dapper to return some data in a DataReader that then gets converted to a DataTable which then gets converted to json and returned to the caller. The schema can change, so I have absolutely *zero* desire to stuff the data into a strongly typed object that I would just have to constantly update for no good reason since it's never used server side. The data is just pulled from the server and then returned to the client which is a web browser that needs json to work with.

My problem is that the project I'm working in uses Entity Framework for everything else and my boss would prefer not to add another dependency (Dapper) to the project. Unless there is a way to get the DataReader or otherwise get a DataTable w/o having a strongly typed object for EF to work with, my next conversation will have to be about whether it's okay for me to just get the data the traditional way with just ADO.net. I assume that's what I will end up having to do, but before I have that conversation I just wanted to verify for certain whether there is a way to get the DataReader or a DataTable with EF because if there is then that's the way I should do it.

Note we're using sql server 2014, so getting a scalar value with for json path is not an option. :(

Comment: Just show this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network. Dapper really isn't one of those many one-day-fly open-source libraries out there.

Comment: @GertArnold I know. My boss likes Dapper and prefers it. But in this particular project, everything already uses EF and he doesn't want to have two frameworks. It's just an ideological thing more than anything else in my opinion. But my question isn't an ideological question... it's just a question of whether this can or can't be done in EF. And if so, how.

Comment: Well, EF and DataTable have nothing in common and EF doesn't provide a DataReader. EF is the last thing to use for getting dynamic data.

Comment: @GertArnold You're preaching to the choir brother, lol!